# Create new record and return new ID

Tags: oracle-apex

Using a modal window, I enter data, then click the button, and then during processing, a new record is created and the modal window is closed.

But now I want that the modal window is not closed and the new ID from the record is stored back, in a hidden text field between.

How can I do that?

I have already googled for nextval.sequence, but have not yet found the right thing I am looking for.

Comment: What version of apex ? Are you using a region of type "form" or your own pl/sql to do the insert ? Apex supports the "RETURNING INTO" clause but how you use it depends on your implementation